# custom validation with client side validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

have two models,

```
 class Quote < ActiveRecord::Base
   attr_accessible :quote_date
   validates :quote_date, :presence => true
end
```

and

```
class Invoice < ActiveRecord::Base
   attr_accessible :invoice_date
   validates :invoice_date, :presence => true


  validate :invoice_date_lesser

  belongs_to :quote

  private
    def invoice_date_lesser
     if invoive_date < quote_date
       errors.add(:invoice_date, 'invoice date invalid')
     end
   end
end
```

would be of great help if i could get some solution as to how to do this validation
and custom validation with client-side validation

Comment: what do you mean client side validation by giving rails code ? using `jquery` you can validate

Comment: he means using the [gem client side validation](https://github.com/bcardarella/client_side_validations/tree/4-0-beta)

Comment: using client_side_validations -sorry for type error

Comment: so have you read the README of that gem ?

Comment: yep, but first i need to get the validation going, was able to custom validate with the values of same model (e.g. discount should be less than amount), but here i need to compare values between of two related models and then get the client_side_validations going

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope I understand your questions.

1. You want to know how to get a validation that using a nested resource
2. You want to know how to make that validation pass through to client side validation

For validations: add the reference to the associated model

```
def invoice_date_lesser
 if invoive_date < quote.quote_date
   errors.add(:invoice_date, 'invoice date invalid')
 end
```

end

For client side validations: add validate => true in your form_for

```
form_for @model, :validate => true do |f|
```